# AlarmManager.SetRepeating not working properly

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-alarms

I'm trying to call a thread regularly through the AlarmManager. Problem is, after the given period the OnReceive() gets called two times (why?) and then never again. What am I doing wrong here?
I'm working with Xamarin (C#) for Android on API level 23.

Code from MainActivity:

```
Alarm alarm = new Alarm ();
RegisterReceiver (alarm, new IntentFilter ("com.company.BROADCAST"));
alarm.SetAlarm(this);
```

Alarm class:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] {"com.company.BROADCAST"})]
public class Alarm : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context c, Intent i)
    {
        Toast.MakeText (c, "hi", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
    {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
        Intent i = new Intent("com.company.BROADCAST");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 1000, 1000 * 2, pi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OnReceive` is being called twice because you have accidentally registered your alarm twice. Let's add the following snippet into your `Alarm` class:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[] {"com.company.BROADCAST"})]
public class Alarm : BroadcastReceiver
{

    public Alarm ()
        : base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Alarm made: " + this.GetHashCode ());
    }

    public Alarm(System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(handle, transfer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Alarm made: " + this.GetHashCode ());
    }

    // ...
}
```

If we run the application, the `Alarm` will log out a unique hash-code for each instance that is created. So start the application up and watch what happens in the Application Output:

```
Alarm made: 123719217
...
Alarm made: 119997678
```

Whoa! We have 2 instances... How did that happen?

The attribute `[IntentFilter(new string[] {"com.company.BROADCAST"})]` generates a manifest entry for your `Alarm : BroadcastReceiver` that will cause it to automatically listen for broadcasts of `com.company.BROADCAST`. The Xamarin docs have a great explanation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#Intent_Actions_and_Features).

The 2nd registration happens when you call `RegisterReceiver` in your activity. This registers a new, unique instance of the `Alarm` to listen for broadcasts of `com.company.BROADCAST`.

You can fix the "alarm being called twice" issue by either removing the `[IntentFilter(new string[] {"com.company.BROADCAST"})]` attribute from `Alarm` or by removing the `RegisterReceiver` call within the activity.

---

Secondly, 2000 milliseconds is too small a frequency for the AlarmManager. It will automatically expand it out to 60 seconds to preserve battery life.

If you run your sample and use logcat to capture the systems output you'll see a message that confirms this:

```
W/AlarmManager(  579): Suspiciously short interval 2000 millis; expanding to 60 seconds
```

If you want to repeat an operation so frequently, consider using a timer or post delayed handler:

```
// Frequent operation using .NET Timer.
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer (1000);
t.AutoReset = true;
t.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) => {
    t.Interval = 2000;
    RunOnUiThread (() => Toast.MakeText (this, "Hi", ToastLength.Short).Show ());
};
t.Start ();

// Frequent operation using Android.OS.Handler
handler = new Handler ();
Action callback = null;
callback = () => {
    //Do something after 100ms
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Hi", ToastLength.Short).Show();  
    handler.PostDelayed(callback, 2000);
};
handler.PostDelayed(callback, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't know this. Do you have any idea why the alarm isn't repeating?

Comment: I'd say a repeat interval of 2000ms is too small. Android normally expands any interval of less than 1minute out to one minute. Let me confirm though